# only on Phone. Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory

Tags: node.js, ionic2

Hello everyone I know this issue exists several times but I looked all of them but couldn't find any solution.I have an ionic app and works all functions however only change profile picture post gives that error on server.

**Client**

```
ChangeTheProfilePicture() {
this.camera.getPicture(this.options).then((imageData) => {

  this.imageURL = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
  var data = {
    img: this.imageURL
  }
  this.http.post('http://myIpAdress:3100/api/addProfilePic', data)
    .subscribe((data1: any) => {
      console.log("done: ", data1);
    }, err => {
      console.log("photo err: ", err);
    })
})}
```

**Server**

```
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,Content-
  Type,Cache-Control");
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.statusCode = 204;

    return res.end();
  }
  else {
    return next();
  }
  });
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
var err = new Error('Not Found');
err.status = 404;
next();
});

// error handlers

if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: err
    });
});
}

//View Engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);


//set static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));
```

When  I take a photo on my phone then press okay button the server side gives an error(it can't even go the routes to get that postapi/addProfilePic).I guess my client side true but in server side setting views folder is wrong.

**File root**

[image]

Thank you

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, the image of size is too big to post it, I will use ionic file transfer.